# Is there an online database of early manuscripts of the Tanakh?

Tags: history, tanach, internet, text, manuscripts

As a student of textual and historical criticism of the Christian scriptures, I am interested in seeing the earliest extant copies of the texts.  There are a number of sites devoted to providing access to some of these papyri, such as [this one](http://www.earlybible.com) and [this one](http://www.csntm.org/manuscript) (don't worry, no theology on these links, and the texts are written in Koine Greek).  I would like to find something similar to this, but related to papyri of the Tanakh.

I know that Judaism is a bit different from Christianity in this regard - as far as I have heard and read, Jews treat the actual documents with reverence, whereas Christians don't really care about the document, only the ideas represented by the words on the documents.  This might make it unacceptable to post images of the texts online, but I really don't know.

Is there an online database of images of the earliest extant manuscripts of the books of the Tanakh?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60257/version-of-the-tanach-that-pre-dates-jesus/60259#60259

Answer (score 6):

The two main texts you probably want to see, in terms of the Masoretic texts, are the [Leningrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leningrad_Codex) and [Aleppo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleppo_Codex) Codices, available online [here](https://archive.org/details/Leningrad_Codex) and [here](https://archive.org/details/Aleppo_Codex) respectively.

See [here](http://animatedhebrew.com/mss/mss_facsimiles.pdf) for many more old scanned manuscripts.

Comment: That last link is exactly what I was looking for.  Codices tend to be much more recent than papyri, so I am more interested in the papyri.  Unfortunately, papyri don't withstand the ravages of time very well, so they are often fragmentary and in extremely poor condition.  I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 5):

- Aleppo Codex: [Archive.org pdf](https://archive.org/details/Aleppo_Codex), [flash version arranged by book](http://aleppocodex.org/flashopen.html)
- Berlin Codex (Babylonian niqqud): [Seforim Online pdf](http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/pdf/265.pdf)
- British Museum Or. 4445 (B): [British Museum](http://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/FullDisplay.aspx?ref=Or_4445)
- Cairo Codex: [Wikipedia pdf](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Cairo-codex-nevi%27im.pdf), [Seforim Online pdf (skewed images, includes intro)](http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/pdf/266.pdf)
- Cairo Genizah: [Cambridge](https://cudl.lib.cam.ac.uk/collections/genizah), [Friedberg Project (partially transcribed)](http://www.jewishmanuscripts.org/)
- Damascus Codex: [World Digital Library](https://www.wdl.org/en/item/11364/view/1/1/), [National Library of Israel djvu](http://jnul.huji.ac.il/dl/mss/heb5702/index_eng.html)
- Dead Sea Scrolls: [Levy Digital Library](http://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/?locale=en_US)
- Leningrad Codex: [Archive.org pdf](https://archive.org/details/Leningrad_Codex), [transcribed (with ms view option)](http://tanach.us/Tanach.xml), [Seforim Online (with intro)](http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/pdf/264.pdf)
- MS Sassoon 1053: [Wikipedia pdfs](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Tanakh-MS-Sassoon-1053)
- Yemenite mss: [Friedberg Project (partially transcribed)](http://www.jewishmanuscripts.org/)